# SQL Server 2005 Database Designer

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2005, database-design

Does anyone know a good and free Database Designer able to export the design into SQL Server 2005 ?

I have been using PowerAMC for 2 weeks but it was the trial. PowerAMC is the only program I know with a Conceptual Data Model Designer.

Thank you.

Comment: +1 For luck.  IME, it was hard enough digging up logical model information relating to SQL Server--let along a free tool

Comment: that may explain why I can't find anything with google :/

Answer (score 1):

[NORMA](http://www.objectrolemodeling.com/AboutORM/ORMTools/NORMA/tabid/87/Default.aspx)? A plug in for Visual Studio (can use Express editions)

This is useful for Conceptual Data Modelling and will generate DDL too